# Why my google map is not showing at contact us page?

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-us, setup-script, google-map

My google map is not displaying and due to script problem. How to resolve this?

[image]

my script code is as follows

```
    function initialize() {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(, );
        var mapOptions = {
            center: pos,
            panControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            scaleControl: true,
            streetViewControl: true,
            overviewMapControl: true,
            zoom: 
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("store_map"), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pos,
            map: map,
            title: ''
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I have already verified this things.

From admin panel, In Porto theme settings i configured properly all this things,

```
System->Configuration->Porto - Settings Panel->Contact Us
```

Verify this field, you have added details.

```
 1. Show Google Map
 2. Address
 3. Latitude
 4. Longitude
```

For more information see screen-sort.
[image]

Comment: please share you script/ code how you use the google map api

Comment: where i can find this?

Comment: in the page where you want to show google map you put script

Comment: at contact us page i want to show. can you tell me the path for contact us page?

Comment: so you didn't put any script yet?

Comment: actually i am using porto magento theme, by default that came. from last two months that was disurbed.

Comment: Go To Admin -> CMS -> Pages . In gird you can find contact us page

Comment: also check your browser console for errors

Comment: i dont have any contact us page in admin

Answer (score 2):

You need to verify this things.

In Porto theme setting you have configured properly all this things,

```
System->Configuration->Porto - Settings Panel->Contact Us
```

Verify this field, you have added details.

```
 1. Show Google Map
 2. Address
 3. Latitude
 4. Longitude
```

For more information see screen-sort.
[image]